# How do I use the Python commands in PowerShell?

Tags: command-line, python, powershell

I work in a GIS department and I'm trying to learn Python to automate something boring. I started using "Learn Python the Hard Way", but I can't figure out how to run Python scripts from PowerShell. I can however use IDLE (Integrated DeveLopment Environment). I've tried using the author's suggestions and I've tried using the full file path, but nothing seems to be working. What do I need to do to be able to run Python scripts from the PowerShell?

Comment: What have you tried already? What was the author's suggestion? What happens when you use this suggestion?

Comment: Have you installed the Python interpreter? What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Check this link: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/win/

Comment: Note: The latest Python 2.7 should have `pip` included.

Comment: How exactly (full command line) are you trying to run the python script? What does it print? Does it work, or prints something when running on "pure" cmd.exe?

Comment: Author recommends using 
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Python27", "User")
I can't really install anything. I'm not really sure if I have Python interpreter. I'm using windows 7. It looks like I'm using Python 2.7.5

Comment: This is the error I get when trying to use the python command in powershell.


The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spel
ling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:7
+ python <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException